# Editar archivo de excel desde php

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Buen dia tengo el siguiente codigo para editar un excel desde php pero cuando lo ejecuto me muestra el siguiente error `C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php on line 60`

Sinceramente estoy empezando a usar PhpSpreadsheet me podrian orientar para saber como poder editar mi archivo de excel o que estoy haciendo mal

```
<?php


    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load("Examen.xlsx");
    try {
    

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setTitle("Almacenistas embarques");
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, 3, "Valor");
    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Xlsx');
    $sheet->setCellValue("B5", "Valor B5");
    $writer->save("test.xlsx");
    
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      echo 'Ocurrió un error al intentar abrir el archivo ' . $e;
    }  

?>
```

De antemano gracias

Comment: Muestra más detalles del error invocando a `$e.getMessage()` o bien revisando el log de errores directamente. Puede ser un problema de permisos, o de que el archivo no existe, etc.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError:PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter(): Argument #1 ($spreadsheet) must be of type PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet, PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL\Edit.php on line 18 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php:60, Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL\Edit.php(18): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet), 'Xlsx')
#1 {main}

Solo me muestra esto

Comment: Ya logre editar mi archivo ahora con lo que batallo es al convertirlo a PDF me arroja un error muy extenso en 2 librerias de phpoffice estoy utilizando `Mpdf`

Comment: Pues lo mismo, muestra el mensaje de error. Recuerda que los mensajes de error deben ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en comentarios. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el mensaje de error, no importa que sea extenso, mejor aún, porque contiene todo la información necesaria para resolver el problema. Si vas a desarrollar, no te asustes de los mensajes de error, trata de entenderlos, te ayudarán a resolver el problema, sin ir a tientas o tratando de adivinar qué es lo que falla.

Comment: Ya lo arregle era una linea de codigo al intentar generar el archivo

Comment: Me alegro. Pero para futuras preguntas, considera agregar el mensaje completo de error, eso es lo más importante a la hora de comprender por qué falla el código. Como dije, no hay que asustarse de la longitud de un mensaje de error, hay que torearlo, partiendo de la línea en donde el código falla, que suele estar al final de dicho mensaje, y leyendo antentamente el motivo del fallo.

Comment: Muchas gracias acabo de publicar una pregunta para ver de que manera puedo corregir el aumento de tamaño al pasar un excel a pdf. ya que al realizar la conversion aumenta bastante la dimension a comparacion del excel

Comment: @A.Cedano me podrias ayudar con la siguiente duda que tengo en mi otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/587254/54170