# Exportar multiples registros de un mismo empleado

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo mi siguiente codigo para editar una plantilla de excel y convertirla a PDF la cual se llena con informacion extraida de mi base de datos mi problema es que mi plantilla es un examen en el cual la columna `I` se deben mostrar las respuestas ingresadas por el empleado cuando realizo el examen en linea.

Mi problema es que cuando extraigo la respuesta en todas las preguntas me pone la misma respusta ya que me esta tomando como referencia la ultima respuesta ingresada por el empleado, lo que quiero saber o si me pueden orientar es como puedo mostrar todas las respuestas que obtengo con la siguiente consulta.

`SELECT * FROM mst_useranswer,empleados WHERE idaso = 253415 AND test_id = 1 AND codigo_persona = 253415 ORDER BY que_id ASC;`

**Esta imagen es el resultado que me muestra la consulta anterior al ejecutarla directamente en la consola de phpmyadmin**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit.php

Este es el codigo que uso para la modificacion y conversion de la plantilla del examen
Se que me toma el ultimo registro por que en columna `B5` extraigo la fecha del examen y me pone la del ultimo registro

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'conexion.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mst_useranswer,empleados WHERE idaso = 253415 AND test_id = 1 AND codigo_persona = 253415 ORDER BY que_id ASC";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);


$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$path ='Examen.xlsx';
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($path);
 
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
 
    while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $sheet->setCellValue('B5', $rows['date']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G4', $rows['Nombre']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G5', $rows['codigo_persona']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I10', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I14', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I18', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I22', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I26', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I30', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I34', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I38', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I42', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I46', $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I49', '10');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C52', $rows['Nombre']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('D53', 'SI');
        $sheet->setCellValue('I53', 'NO');
        $namefile = $rows['codigo_persona'];
    }
    
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Mpdf");
    $pdf_path = "$namefile.pdf";
    //$writer->save($pdf_path);
    //$writer->save('Hostel_.xlsx');

    if (!file_exists('files')) {
        mkdir('files', 0755);
    }
    $writer->save('files/'.$pdf_path);

    $dir = 'files/';

    $new_name_file = $dir . $pdf_path;

    $ins = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO files(title,description,url) VALUES ('','','$new_name_file')");

    if ($ins) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }


?>
```

Este es mi resultado al ejecutar el php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando ejecutas esta consulta **SELECT * FROM mst_useranswer,empleados WHERE idaso = 253415 AND test_id = 1 AND codigo_persona = 253415 ORDER BY que_id ASC;** directamente en la consola sql de phpmyadmin que resultados te arroja?

Comment: El de la imagen que esta agregada en la pregunta

Comment: Me muestra los datos de la tabla `mst_useranswer` y la tabla `empleados` y esos datos son los de la primer imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas sobreescribiendo todo el rato el valor de todas las celdas [I10-I46] con el valor de:

```
$rows['your_ans']
```

Entonces al final queda el último valor de la última row, que es un 1. Hazlo así así te fucionará por que encada iteración dentro del while incrementamos el "contador" de la celda que quieres plasmar el valor de "your_ans"

```
$fila_num = 10;
$sumaTotal = 0;

while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $sheet->setCellValue('B5', $rows['date']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G4', $rows['Nombre']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G5', $rows['codigo_persona']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $fila_num, $rows['your_ans']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I49', '10');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C52', $rows['Nombre']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('D53', 'SI');
        $sheet->setCellValue('I53', 'NO');
        $fila_num += 4;
        $sumaTotal += $rows['your_ans'];
        $namefile = $rows['codigo_persona'];
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente como me dijsite y me muestra el siguiente error `Warning: Undefined array key 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL - Copy\Edit.php on line 23

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL - Copy\Edit.php on line 23`

Comment: he editado la respuesta, tiene que funcionar ahora. Si falla, saca y muestra por consola el valor de $resultado justo despues de hacer la consulta.

Comment: `$sheet->setCellValue('B5', $resultado[ultimaFila]['date']);` en esta linea la palabra ultimafila es la misma variable que declaraste arriba o la escribo talcual sin el signo `$` y todo eso dentro del while verdad

Comment: Sin el while. y siempre con $ las variables en php (rectificado)

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL - Copy\Edit.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDFEXCEL - Copy\Edit.php on line 21`

Comment: Anexe a tu respujesta como lo tengo yo

Comment: Dale! ahora sí que sí. Ahora no hay opción de que no te funcione!

Comment: Eres todo un crack me funciono. sabes que yo lo intente asi poniendo la celda 10 y despues sumando 4 pero solo ponia en mi caso $i +4 entonces lo que hacia era solo una celda brincaba y las demas las ponia debajo pero no como tu muchas gracias

Comment: Solo una duda mas ahora esos resultados si los quisiera sumar como podria hacerlo yo habia pensado en usar mejor un count pero creo que saldra mejor realizar una suma o tu que opinas

Comment: Me alegro de que funcione! ya era algo casi personal XD. Ahroa te edito para que te sume, es facil por que ya nos funciona el rollete XD

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144682/discussion-between-ferter3006-and-alberto-cruz).